# I keep getting the error System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'SQL logic error near "into": syntax error'

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite

I cannot figure out what is wrong with code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqb1c.png)

System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'SQL logic error
near "into": syntax error'

```
    private void BtnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string StudentIDq = "update into Student (StudentID, ExamBoard, Firstname, Surname, Pure, Statistics, Mechanics, Total, " + "Average, Rank) values ('" + txtStudentID.Text + ", " + cmbExamBoard + ", " + txtFirstname.Text + "," + "" + txtSurname.Text + "," + txtPure.Text + ", " + txtStats.Text + "," + txtMechanics.Text + " + " + txtTS.Text + "," + txtAvrg.Text + "," + txtRank.Text + ")";


        ExecuteQuery(StudentIDq);
        LoadData();


    }
```

Comment: Just replace `update into` with `insert into`.

Comment: Also read up on sql injection.

Answer (score -1):

```
  private void BtnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string StudentIDq = "insert into Student (StudentID, ExamBoard, Firstname, Surname, Pure, Statistics, Mechanics, Total, " + "Average, Rank) values ('" + txtStudentID.Text + ", " + cmbExamBoard + ", " + txtFirstname.Text + "," + "" + txtSurname.Text + "," + txtPure.Text + ", " + txtStats.Text + "," + txtMechanics.Text + " + " + txtTS.Text + "," + txtAvrg.Text + "," + txtRank.Text + ")";


    ExecuteQuery(StudentIDq);
    LoadData();


}
```

Comment: It doesnt work it still gives me the error System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'SQL logic error
unrecognized token: "'123, System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox, Items.Count: 4, qw,w2,56, 56,89 + 89,89,1)""

Answer (score -1):

If you are updating the columns the query will be like

```
    string StudentIDq = "update Student set StudentID=" + txtStudentID.Text + ", ExamBoard= " + cmbExamBoard + ", Firstname='" + txtFirstname.Text + "', Surname='" + txtSurname.Text + "', Pure='" + txtPure.Text + "', Statistics='" + txtStats.Text + "', Mechanics='" + txtMechanics.Text + "' , Total=" + txtTS.Text + ", " + "Average=" + txtAvrg.Text + ", Rank=" + txtRank.Text + ") ;
```

Also add a Where condition,otherwise all columns will get updated